# Setting the background color of a FlowDocument in a FlowDocumentReader

Tags: wpf, flowdocumentreader

I have been using a `RichTextBox` to show `FlowDocuments` in a WPF app, but I found that there is something called `FlowDocumentReader`which gives me alot of functionality for free. The problem is that while the background in the RichTextBox was shown as white, it is now completely transparent.

I have tried setting the `Background`property, but that only changes the toolbar at the bottom.

```
<FlowDocumentReader Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Name="rtbShowDoc" Margin="20, 0" Background="White">
    <FlowDocumentReader.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="10" Color="Black" ShadowDepth="3" />
    </FlowDocumentReader.Effect>
</FlowDocumentReader>
```

[image: Background set]

I can do an ugly fix with a `DockPanel`, but that does not seem like the right way to do it.

```
<DockPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="20, 0" Background="White">
    <DockPanel.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="10" Color="Black" ShadowDepth="3" />
    </DockPanel.Effect>
    <FlowDocumentReader Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Name="rtbShowDoc" Background="White">
    </FlowDocumentReader>
</DockPanel>
```

How can I set the background of a FlowDocumentReader?

**EDIT:** Added screenshot of running application. As you can see the dropshadow effect is applied to all text inside the `FlowDocument`.
[image: Running application]

Comment: That looks like design mode.  When you run it and load a FlowDocument is the background not white?

Comment: No, it looks exactly the same. I took a screenshot of design mode to show that it is not my databound `FlowDocument` that somehow affects the style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the background of the FlowDocument

[FlowDocument.Background Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.flowdocument.background%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you, I used a `Style` to set the `Background` property since my `Flowdocuments` are databound and that worked nicely, not sure why I didn't think of that myself ;)

Answer (score 0):

In C#:

```
FlowDocument.Background = Brushes.Red;
```